# smartgwt inline text plus form items

Tags: forms, inline, smartgwt, word-wrap

I am trying to setup a template form using smartgwt that combines text plus form items, but I don't know what smartgwt structure is best suited. This is what I am trying to do:

1. The basic form is some predefined long text,
2. At some predefined places in the text, insert form widgets, like a combo box or a date picker.
3. The whole structure should be presented to the user as continuous text with the options to select on the combobox, date, etc.
4. The text should wrap around the end of lines of the containing element (a paragraph container)
5. The form inputs (combobox, etc) should flow next to the end of the preceding text in the same line.

(I would post an image for clarification but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation)

The problem I am experiencing with smartgwt forms is that they are presented to the user within a table structure using rows and columns that doesn't fit the concept of continuous text. My text is wrapped around the containing cell of the table and the flow of the form is lost.

If I set the text to no wrap with .setWrap(false), then the text doesn't wrap in the containing cell, but it doesn't wrap either at the end of the line for the paragraph stracture. It is difficult to use 'colspan' and 'rowspan' because the size of the text varies for different templates.

Any ideas on how to implement this? Any help appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below mathods:

- [FormItem#setShowClippedTitleOnHover()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#setShowClippedTitleOnHover%28boolean%29).
- [FormItem#setShowClippedValueOnHover()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#setShowClippedValueOnHover%28java.lang.Boolean%29)
- [FormItem#setClipTitle()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#setClipTitle%28java.lang.Boolean%29)
- [StaticTextItem#setClipValue()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/StaticTextItem.html#setClipValue%28java.lang.Boolean%29)

---

Try below sample code:

```
DynamicForm dynamicForm = new DynamicForm();

StaticTextItem textItem=new StaticTextItem();
textItem.setTitle("Description");
textItem.setValue("A very very very very long description");
textItem.setWidth(60);

textItem.setWrap(false);//no wrap
textItem.setWrapTitle(false);//no wrap

textItem.setClipTitle(true);
textItem.setShowClippedTitleOnHover(true);//show title on hover if clipped

textItem.setClipValue(true);
textItem.setShowClippedValueOnHover(true);//show value on hover if clipped

dynamicForm.setItems(textItem);
dynamicForm.setWidth(75);

RootPanel.get().add(dynamicForm);
```

screenshots:

[image]

[image]